# Remove tooltip when scrolling a table

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

There is a table on one of the pages of the site. Some table cells have icons (from mui) with a tooltip. When you hover over the icon, a tooltip appears.

Here a problem arises: if the tooltip is open and the table is scrolled, then the tooltip flies out of the table borders.

Below is the code with the cell that contains the icon

```
    export default function TableCell() {
  return (
    <TableRow className="TableCellStyle">
      <TableCell>
        <Tooltip
          title="Download"
          arrow
          componentsProps={{
            tooltip: {
              sx: {
                bgcolor: "#a3a3a3",
                "& .MuiTooltip-arrow": {
                  color: "#a3a3a3"
                }
              }
            }
          }}
          PopperProps={{
            modifiers: [
              {
                name: "offset",
                options: {
                  offset: [0, -8]
                }
              }
            ]
          }}
        >
          <FileDownloadIcon />
        </Tooltip>
      </TableCell>
      <TableCell>Some Text</TableCell>
      <TableCell>Some Text</TableCell>
      <TableCell>Some Text</TableCell>
      <TableCell>Some Text</TableCell>
      <TableCell>Some Text</TableCell>
      <TableCell>Some Text</TableCell>
      <TableCell>Some Text</TableCell>
    </TableRow>
  );
}
```

Tell me how to make the tooltip disappear if the table scrolls

Update: so far there was an answer that when hovering over the tooltip, the scrolling of the table would disappear altogether. But that doesn't quite work for me. I would like the tooltip to disappear as soon as the scroll starts.

Comment: which icon? do you mean the button?

Comment: tmk that wouldn't be an issue tbh ..

Comment: Ok, kinda icky... but I [made it work with React context](https://codesandbox.io/s/solitary-glade-8tw1bd?file=/src/FileDownloadButton.jsx)... let me know if this is OK and I'll write an answer.

Comment: @caTS Thanks for pay attention my question, but this solution doesn't work correctly. Even if you open the table in full screen in the code-sandbox, you can see that the tooltip does not disappear, but scrolls along with the table

Comment: Add a scroll event listener to table body, throttle the events, and on scroll disable all open tooltips by calling close or remove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import `useEffect()` from React and add this function to the FileDownloadButton.jsx component:

#### Method 1: Using basic JS

```
useEffect(() => {
    const scrollableElements = [
      document.querySelector(".TableBodyStyle"),
      document
    ];
    scrollableElements.forEach((element) => {
      element.addEventListener("scroll", (event) => {
        const tooltip = document.querySelector("[role='tooltip']");
        if (tooltip) {
          tooltip.style.display = "none";
        }
      });
    });
  });
```

What we're doing is checking to see if the tooltip is visible, and if it is, we're setting the display to none when the table is scrolled.

A cleaner way would be to call the Tooltip's inbuilt hide function, that way you would retain the hiding animation. I've not used React before though, so I'm unsure of how to programmatically call the functions of a child component. If you know how to do that, you can substitute the code inside the listener with that function call instead.

Here's what the current method looks like: https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-ritchie-f9jizd?file=/src/FileDownloadButton.jsx

### Edit

#### Method 2: Using React state

So I did a bit of reading and was able to figure out how to solve this issue using react state. It is almost the same as above, we just need to create a state variable and setter function, and call the setter inside the eventHandler.

This is what it'll look like:

```
const [showTooltip, setShowTooltip] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    const scrollableElements = [
      document.querySelector(".TableBodyStyle"),
      document
    ];
    scrollableElements.forEach((element) => {
      element.addEventListener("scroll", (event) => {
        setShowTooltip(false)
      });
    });
  });
```

For this method you will also need to pass these values as props to the Tooltip component.

```
<Tooltip
    title="Show item"
    arrow
    open={showTooltip}
    onOpen={()=> { setShowTooltip(true) }}
    onClose={()=> { setShowTooltip(false) }}
    componentsProps={{
      tooltip: {
        sx: {
          bgcolor: "#a3a3a3",
          "& .MuiTooltip-arrow": {
          color: "#a3a3a3"
          }
        }
      }
    }}
    PopperProps={{
      modifiers: [
        {
          name: "offset",
          options: {
            offset: [0, -8]
          }
        }
      ]
    }}
  >
```

This is what the new method would look like: https://codesandbox.io/s/hide-tooltip-using-react-6ctu7y?file=/src/FileDownloadButton.jsx

Comment: This is the best decision that could be made. Everything works great!!! The first option worked best for me. Thank you very much! You are a great programmer

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possible solution:

**Strategy**:
Use a state variable to define when you want the table body to be scroll-able and when not to. On enter and exit of hover you can toggle the state and apply conditional styling to html.

**Sandbox link**:
https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-margulis-25h1gh?file=/src/DevicesTableCell.jsx

**Code**:

```
export default function DevicesTableCell({ setAllowScroll }) {
  return (
    <TableRow className="TableCellStyle">
      <TableCell>
        <Tooltip
          title="Download item"
          arrow
          onOpen={() => {
            setAllowScroll(false);
          }}
          onClose={() => {
            setAllowScroll(true);
          }}
          componentsProps={{
            tooltip: {
              sx: {
                bgcolor: "#a3a3a3",
                "& .MuiTooltip-arrow": {
                  color: "#a3a3a3"
                }
              }
            }
          }}
          PopperProps={{
            modifiers: [
              {
                name: "offset",
                options: {
                  offset: [0, -8]
                }
              }
            ]
          }}
        >
          <FileDownloadIcon />
        </Tooltip>
      </TableCell>
      <TableCell>Some Text</TableCell>
      <TableCell>Some Text</TableCell>
      <TableCell>Some Text</TableCell>
      <TableCell>Some Text</TableCell>
      <TableCell>Some Text</TableCell>
      <TableCell>Some Text</TableCell>
      <TableCell>Some Text</TableCell>
    </TableRow>
  );
}
```

```
export default function DevicesTable() {
  const [allowScroll, setAllowScroll] = useState(true);
  return (
    <TableContainer className="TableContainerGridStyle">
      <Table className="TableStyle">
        <DevicesTableHeader />
        <TableBody
          className="TableBodyStyle"
          style={!allowScroll ? { overflow: "hidden" } : {}}
        >
          <DevicesTableCell setAllowScroll={setAllowScroll} />
          <DevicesTableCell setAllowScroll={setAllowScroll} />
          <DevicesTableCell setAllowScroll={setAllowScroll} />
          <DevicesTableCell setAllowScroll={setAllowScroll} />
          <DevicesTableCell setAllowScroll={setAllowScroll} />
          <DevicesTableCell setAllowScroll={setAllowScroll} />
          <DevicesTableCell setAllowScroll={setAllowScroll} />
          <DevicesTableCell setAllowScroll={setAllowScroll} />
          <DevicesTableCell setAllowScroll={setAllowScroll} />
          <DevicesTableCell setAllowScroll={setAllowScroll} />
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </TableContainer>
  );
}
```

Comment: We cannot send data from child to parent, what we did here was passing down the setter function to child so we can change the state value in child. If you have 2 components (as you said 1 intermediate component) all you have to do is pass down the setter function 2 times i.e., from parent to intermediate and intermediate to child. Does that clear  your doubt?