# Material UI Tooltip inside Autocomplete does not hide on scroll

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have an autocomplete, and I need to show a tooltip on each option, everything works fine, but the problem is the tooltip does not hide immediately on scroll and it goes off of the autocomplete. you can see it in the attached image

[image]

here is the code I use for tooltip inside autocomplete:

```
    <Autocomplete
      size="small"
      multiple
      options={componentTypes}
      value={selected}
      groupBy={option => option.group}
      disableCloseOnSelect
      loading={isFetching}
      onChange={handleChange}
      sx={{ width: 300 }}
      className={className}
      renderOption={(props, option) => (
        <Tooltip title={option.entityLogicalName} key={option.entityLogicalName} leaveDelay={0} disableInteractive>
          <li {...props}>{option.label}</li>
        </Tooltip>
      )}
      renderInput={params => {
        return <TextField label="component types" {...params} />;
      }}
      
    />
```

I tried these methods but it does not work for this problem:
[ToolTip does not disappear on scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74079308/tooltip-does-not-disappear-on-scroll) and
[Remove tooltip when scrolling a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74107445/remove-tooltip-when-scrolling-a-table)